# Does File.Delete(path) use the server's credentials or the users credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, directory

The web site is using windows authentication.

I am getting an error on my custom error page this idea worked fine when we were hosting a dev site that we had access to the directory.

But now I wonder if the site is being denied access for it's read/write permissions

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            string path = Server.MapPath("~/UserData/ErrorLog/");
            int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
            if (fileCount > 10)
            {
                //Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/UserData/ErrorLog/"),true);
                string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");
                foreach (string f in txtList)
                {
                    File.Delete(f);
                }


                //Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/UserData/")+"ErrorLog/");
            }
            // Put user code to initialize the page here
            //Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            Exception ex = (Exception)Application["LastError"];
            string message = ex.ToString();
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
            string filename = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/UserData/ErrorLog/") + "Error" + date + ".log";

            //more code that is irrelevant
    }
```

Comment: I _believe_ it uses the IIS user's credentials.

Comment: if running locally it uses the users local credentials if running remotely or should I say from a web application it will use IIS settings if setup properly if the application can be used by many users.. the IIS admin would not want to grant rights to every user to much manual setup..so usually there is an IIS_USER permissions setup for that particular process

Comment: also readup on how to use `try{}catch{}` when running a process for example wrap the `File.Delete(f) around a try catch and your Exception handling.. the way you are doing it is not what I would consider the best approach.

Comment: it depends. what is the current principal?

Comment: right click folder =>properties =>security=>Edit=>Add=>Network and Network Service=>give all right to these user and then check

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I don't have access to folder or the Network Drive it's on.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can You expand on this?

Comment: Paste Here Exact error what you are getting

Comment: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar the error is on a custom error page. So the error is "error on custom error page.... terminating". I made changes in response to DJ KRAZE's comment I'm just waiting for our hosting group to upload the site to production (they're in no means quick)